# Why do not SessionEvents listeners for Facebook login and logout?

Tags: java, android, facebook, listener, logcat

I encountered the following problem - when integrating Facebook in my application, I have implemented the key to login / logout. She had to call up the authorization and replace text in a button after authentication is successful. If the user is already logged in - she had to call a method to logout and also change the text in the button after the logout. Along the way, I ran to the fact that when you call the authorization I endlessly spinning progress and in the end nothing happened, but that I got rid of  this Facebook prank. So the problem is that they are login and logout are correct, but - there is no change in the text, and the log is also not working.
 What's the problem? I hope for your help.

```
facebookButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.facebook_button);
        facebookButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (facebookProvider.getFacebook().isSessionValid()) {
                    Log.d("YES", "");
                    SessionEvents.LogoutListener logoutListener = new     SessionEvents.LogoutListener() {

                    public void onLogoutFinish() {
                        facebookButton.setText("Login");
                        Log.d("Logout", "Finish");
                    }

                    public void onLogoutBegin() {
                        Log.d("Logout", "Begin");
                        // 
                    }
                };
                SessionEvents.addLogoutListener(logoutListener);
                facebookProvider.facebookLogout();
                Log.d("Logout", "");
            } 
            else {
                Log.d("NO", "");
                SessionEvents.AuthListener loginListener = new SessionEvents.AuthListener() {

                    public void onAuthSucceed() {
                        facebookButton.setText("Logout");
                        Log.d("Login", "Succeed");
                    }

                    public void onAuthFail(String error) {
                        Log.d("Login", "Fail");
                        //
                    }
                };
                SessionEvents.addAuthListener(loginListener);
                facebookProvider.facebookLogin();
                Log.d("Login", "");
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: try to use this library, its really sample and efficient. http://code.google.com/p/android-query/

Comment: @Anis  Thanks for the offer, but your words do not explain why my code does not work, but this line works fine:
....
facebookProvider.facebookLogin ();
facebookButton.setText ("Logout");
....